# Can I use non-default datatype as argument for functions in 1 line?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I think the title of question is little bit confusing, so I'll explain that.

Let's see this very simple code.

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
    int val;

    C(){
        val = 2;
    }

    void changeVal(int i){
        val = i;
    }

};

void printout(int val){
    std::cout << "int val : " << val << std::endl;
}

void printout(C c){
    std::cout << "class val : " << c.val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    printout(1);
    printout(c);    

    //printout(C());    // ok, I can understand it.
    //printout(C().changeVal(0)); /// ?????
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, function *'printout'* is for printing out the input argument.
My question is, when I use the int value(default datatype), then I just put in the function real number '1', however, when I use my class instance('class C'), then I have to declare my class instance before the function.

So, is there any way to make this kind of **non-default datatype for function argument in 1-line**?

The actual situation is, I have to use the 4x4 matrix as argument for some function.
For this reason, I have to make some matrix, and initialize(make zero) that, and use it.
But if I can do this same job with just 1 line, my source code will be more clear than now.

That's my question. I hope you could understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the C tag.  The use of `class` and `<iostream>` implies that this question is about C++ only

Comment: do you mean can you do `printout(C())`

Comment: Btw not sure what you mean by "Default datatype", "built in language datatype/primitive type" would be better

Comment: @simonc Thank you for your guide. I'm not familiar this system

Comment: @KarthikT Oh, that kinds of representation is much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a temporary:

```
printout(C());
```

Note that, since you don't need a copy of the `C` parameter, it would make more sense to pass it by const reference:

```
void printout(const C& c) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I want to ask one more question. Can I use my member function for initialization with similar way?

Comment: I added 'changeVal' function. I want to initialize my member variable 'val' as 0, then I'll use 'changeVal' function for that. Can I do this job in 1 line for function argument?

Comment: @CIMPLE if you want to initialize `val` to `0`, you don't need to call `changeVal`. You can write the default constructor like this: `C() : val(0) {}` or even `C() : val() {}`.